# Revert a git commit with git reset. I used "main" instead of "HEAD". Is it an issue?

Tags: github

I used these commands to roll back one of my git commits:

```
$ git switch main
$ git reset --hard main~1
$ git push origin main --force-with-lease
```

Even though everything worked fine, I noticed that many people use `HEAD~1` instead of `main~1`. Did I do something wrong by using `main~1` instead of `HEAD~1`? `main` is the only branch I had in the repository when I did the reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works fine if you are on the `main` branch currently.

`HEAD` references the currently checked-out commit. If you have checked out the `main` branch then `HEAD` and `main` both reference the same thing.

To test this you can use `git rev-parse HEAD` or `git rev-parse main` which will result in the same hash code if you have checked out the main branch.

The `git reset --hard HEAD~1` works on all branches to undo the latest commit of this branch.

If you use `git reset --hard main~1` on branch `develop` you will hard reset your `develop` branch to the second latest commit on branch `main` which is probably NOT what you wanted.

I tested it out with some sample hash codes for you. Feel free to check out different branches in your project and check which commit is referenced by `HEAD`.

```
git checkout main
git rev-parse main
# Some hash like 54668ebf7678bef9f6274a8c3bc91e1bdef3cde5
git rev-parse HEAD
# Same hash code still like 54668ebf7678bef9f6274a8c3bc91e1bdef3cde5
git rev-parse develop
# Other hash code like aa9f1cccadf548913c582793ec3cda4dd4ec019a
```

Now, if you are on develop, `HEAD` will look at `develop` and not at `main`.

```
git checkout develop
git rev-parse main
# main hash 54668ebf7678bef9f6274a8c3bc91e1bdef3cde5
git rev-parse HEAD
# develop hash aa9f1cccadf548913c582793ec3cda4dd4ec019a
git rev-parse develop
# develop hash aa9f1cccadf548913c582793ec3cda4dd4ec019a
```

Comment: I haven't created any separate branch beside `main`. `main` is the only branch in the repo. I created the repo last Sunday so it's relatively new. I ran `git rev-parse HEAD` and `git rev-parse main` and the hashes match, but I ran the commands now that the reset has been already done. Is that okay?

Comment: If you only have one branch, then `HEAD`and `main`are exactly the same! You did everything correct! `HEAD`is just a more generalized way of saying: I want the latest commit of the current branch.